# subform always goes to first in recordset - i need the last one

Tags: forms, ms-access-2016

I have a main form for submersible dives (dives recordset) and a subform which shows every specimen collected by the submersible (specimen recordset).  The main form has text boxes, buttons and checkboxes, as does the subform. If I click a button in the subform to add a new specimen, I get a new blank record. When the user selects from a dropdown the specimen type (biological, geological or water), the specimen ID is assigned based on datetime and type and the next consecutive number read from the dives recordset.  (i.e. cruiseID_datetime_divenn_specxx_bio, where nn is the dive number and xx is the next consecutive number of a collected specimen)  This is working fine.  My problem is that if the user's cursor then moves to the main form over any of the five checkbox controls and only one of 19 buttons on the main form, the main form and the subform refresh and I am back at the first specimen for that dive.  All other buttons and text boxes on the mai form cause this refresh behavior.  There are no mouse move events or any places that I can find that would cause a refresh just by my moving my mouse over just those 6 controls.  I am just so stumped!

Comment: Correction: All other buttons and text boxes on the main form DO NOT cause this refresh behavior.

Comment: You delete the button, then create a new or make a copy of one of the behaving buttons.